# Find the trace of the 2nd power adjacency matrix(Not simple graph)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, solution-verification

Find the $tr(A^2)$ [Here the $A$ is the adjacency matrix of the below graph]

[image]

In simple graph, $tr(A^2) = \sum d(v_i)$ [Here the $d(v_i)$ is a degree of the vertex, $v_i$]

But this is not simple graph, So I can't use the above formula. Therefore I calculated the number of the walk which length is $2$ and $v_i \to v_i$

$(1)$ $v_1 \to v_1$ : there are $5$ walks

- $v_1 \to v_2 \to v_1$  : there are $1$ walks.
- $v_1 \to v_4 \to v_1$  : there are $4$ walks.

$(2)$ $v_2 \to v_2$  : there are $3$ walks.

- $v_2 \to v_1 \to v_2$  : there are $1$ walks.
- $v_2 \to v_3 \to v_2$  : there are $1$ walks.
- $v_2 \to v_4 \to v_2$  : there are $1$ walks.

$(3)$ $v_3 \to v_3$ : there are $10$ walks.

- $v_3 \to v_2 \to v_3$  : there are $1$ walks.
- $v_3 \to v_4 \to v_3$  : there are $9$ walks.

$(4)$ $v_4 \to v_4$ : there are $14$ walks.

- $v_4 \to v_3 \to v_4$  : there are $9$ walks.
- $v_4 \to v_2 \to v_4$  : there are $1$ walks.
- $v_4 \to v_1 \to v_4$  : there are $4$ walks.

So my answer is $32$. Is my things right? Plus, Does the formula $tr(A^2) = \sum d(v_i)$ only hold for simple graph?

Comment: Your computation is correct, and it shows that for non-simple graphs, $\operatorname{tr}(A^2)$ is not the sum of the vertex degrees.  In fact, it's the sum of the squares of the elements of $A$ (proof?).

Comment: @saulspatz, Ah yes. Thanks for your comment. And plus,  Would you suggest the proof for your claim? (The proof for the $tr(A^2)$ is the sum of the squares of the element)

Comment: Just look at how you did the calculation in this case.

Comment: @saulspatz Cool! I figured out why does it. :) Thank you.